# Unity switch between transitions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this animator diagram:

[image]

I want the idle state of my object to be "Idle",but when the user clicks space i want him to "Jump".Here is my code

```
private Animation anim;
private Animator animator;

private void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) { }
}
```

Now I don't know what to write inside of that if statement in order to play the "Jump" state rather than "Idle".

Answer (score 0):

I created a parameter "Jump" and set a condition from entry to allow this transition only if jump is true and when the user clicks space:

```
    animator.SetBool("Jump",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve what you want.

First is you can create animator's parameters/triggers and create a transition between the animation states (in your case **Idle** => **Jump**) which you can check the doc here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html

The other way is play the animation state directly in the code.

```
// Precalculated hash for animation state for more performance
public static int JUMP_STATE = Animator.StringToHash("Jump");
private Animator _animator;

void Start () {
    _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("Jump")){
        // Play the state directly
        _animator.Play(JUMP_STATE);
        // Or you can just call like below if you don't use precalculated hash
        // _animator.Play("Jump");
    }
}
```

for more info you can check the doc https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html